# What's the current state of Yang–Mills mass gap question?

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, open-problems

What's the current state of Yang–Mills mass gap question, is there any place that does this problem? Especially I want to know if there is any progress (out of that mentioned in the introduction article by Witten and Jaffe). Is it too hard for a mathematician? Thanks!

Comment: http://marcofrasca.wordpress.com/2010/09/03/sannino-and-the-mass-gap-in-yang-mills-theory/

Comment: Added tag: open-problem

Comment: http://marcofrasca.wordpress.com/2010/12/01/current-status-of-yang-mills-mass-gap-question/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's some guidelines about open problems in the FAQ that you might want to read, but there was a good article by Faddeev last November that you should know about:

[Mass in Quantum Yang-Mills Theory, by Faddeev](http://arxiv.org/abs/0911.1013)

Answer (score 3):

There is a rather strange situation here because a russian mathematician, Alexander Dynin, is claiming to have solved it. Please, refer to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/176029/some-explanation-about-dynins-formalism) of mine or [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1005.3779) published in a reputable journal. Till now I have not seen any reaction from the community but I think that an analysis of the work of this author is overdue. Indeed, he has worked on this since 2009 as I can see from arxiv.

Answer (score 1):

For the 3D version of the proble, see

[1] Dimitra Karabali and V. P. Nair, Int. J. Mod. Phys. A 12, 1161 (1997)
http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9610002

See eqn (20), (21) and the following paragraph.

Comment: While it provides some explanations, the problem treated there is in 3 dimensions only, while the Clay Millennium problem asks for a solution in 4 dimensions, where extra difficulties show up.

Comment: I forgot to mention 3D. Thanks for the correction.